# Hyperledger fabric applications clarification

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

When people say that Hyperledger fabric is for enterprises solutions it means that the nodes could be the users that are granted access? or it has to be different enterprises cooperating?

Would granting access to the users through unique phone number be feasible?

Sorry for the dumb questions it's for a uni project and I can't find clear informations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fabric is a private/permissioned block chain, and only verified nodes can participate.
In order to verify the nodes on the Internet network, that is, to verify the identity, a PKI system is common.[wikipedia/PKI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_key_infrastructure#:%7E:text=A%20public%20key%20infrastructure%20(PKI,and%20manage%20public%2Dkey%20encryption.))
That is, each node has its own private key and certificate (public key) with authority, and in Fabric, it is controlled under the name of MSP (Membership Service Provider). [Fabric MSP](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/msp.html)

- MSP is easy to get confused by their name, but they can be seen as somthinmg... files of crypto-config artifacts rather than objects that take action.

---

`Would granting access to the users through unique phone number be feasible - Lorenzo Bonelli?`

In fact, it is difficult to answer this question. First of all, I wonder if you are a developer, what is the background, and what is the target system.

First of all, I will assume that you basically know the structure of hyperledger-fabric.
Looking at the question, I think that the identity of a specific subject is digitally mapped to a phone number. Here, I think that users mean clients and peers in the fabric.

#### 1.client

In the case of a client, it can be applied very easily. clients must be given a unique name during the registration process. of course, since the phone number must be able to be changed or modified, it seems to be correct to perform a separate mapping at the application level.

```
userID: 82+10-4036-xxxx
```

#### 2. peer

In the case of peers, it seems that they can map this to their own name.
For example, when building a peer in a fabric network,
It is written in the expression of <peer_name>.<org_name>.<domain_name> like 
`peer0.org0.example.com`

In this process, peer_name can be mapped to a phone number.
`82+10-4036-xxxx.org0.example.com`

---

Of course, the problem that occurs in the above process is that it is difficult to respond flexibly when the phone number is changed. in order to solve this part, it is desirable to implement a separate mapping table

- When you create a mapping table, you have to think about who will manage how.
- In the end, it is necessary to implement middleware in a form that requires the identity resolver/registry of the blockchain network.
- Consider how to operate and manage it from the perspective of the blockchain.
- to put it simply, middleware construction is required on the front of the blockchain, and pay attention to the philosophy of the blockchain..

```
(ex)
| number | uuid |
| 82+10 | '1b9d6bcd-bbfd-4b2d-9b5d-ab8dfbbd4bed' |

client): '1b9d6bcd-bbfd-4b2d-9b5d-ab8dfbbd4bed'
peer): 1b9d6bcd-bbfd-4b2d-9b5d-ab8dfbbd4bed.org0.example.com
```

If it tells you a more specific situation or goal, I'll consider a more appropriate form.